# Linux adding filename and path to text file on a single line

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to write a script to add the name of a file and the directory path to a text file on a single line.
E.g.

```
Filename /root/folder/folder/
```

I've tried:

```
ls "$1" >> /root/folder/folder/file.txt
pwd >> /root/folder/folder/file.txt
```

But it shows up on seperate lines.

I did try

```
ls "$1" && pwd >> ......
```

but it only pasted the pwd to the text file.

I'm new to Linux so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
echo "$1 $(pwd)" >> outputfile
```

Comment: Or maybe `$(pwd)/$1` to get the output in a directly usable format.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
p1=`ls $1`
p2=`pwd`
echo $p1 $p2 >> /root/folder/folder/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "$1$(pwd)" >> /root/folder/folder/file.txt
```

Or you can create a new variable with the concatenated string and then echo that:

```
NewVar="$1$(pwd)"
echo "$NewVar" >> /root/folder/folder/file.txttxt
```

In the first example you have above, each command inserts a newline. In the second example, the `&&` that you have breaks up the two commands so that the output of the first is not redirected. You can't distribute redirection across the `&&`, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

A common technique is to use `printf` (or `echo -n`, but that's less portable) to avoid writing the newline:

```
exec >> /root/folder/folder/file.txt
printf "%s " "$1"
pwd
```

In your example, you use a command to generate the initial data, and a good technique in that case is to use `tr` to trim the newline

```
ls "$1" | tr -d '\012'
printf " "  # Insert a space
pwd
```